# Calling super class constructor from grandchild class, calls parent or grandparent constructor?

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor, super, constructor-overloading

When using a super class constructor from a second-level child class does it pass the argument to the grandparent constructor or the immediate parent constructor?

```
//top class
public First(type first){
  varFirst = first;
}

//child of First
public Second(type second){
  super(second); //calls First(second)
}

//child of Second
public Third(type third){
  super(third); //calls First(third) or Second(third)?
}
```

Comment: assuming type (Class Type as per naming conventions) is same for all 3 Classes , and varFirst is also an instance of Type , then **Yes** , sample example you can try out : replace type with **int** and at each constructor System.out.println(intValue); -> constructor Third will pass a value say *2* to Second and to First BUT printing of sysout will be of order First-Second-Third (in short Third will only invoke Second BUT Second will invoke First and the flow goes on)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`super` calls the constructor of the immediate parent. So the `super` call in `Third` would call `Second`'s constructor, which, in turn, call `First`'s. This is quite easy to see for yourself if you add some print statement in the constructors:

```
public class First {
    public First(String first) {
        System.out.println("in first");
    }
}

public class Second extends First {
    public Second(String second) {
        super(second);
        System.out.println("in second");
    }
}

public class Third extends Second {
    public Third(String third) {
        super(third);
        System.out.println("in third");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Third("yay!");
    }
}
```

The output you'd get:

```
in first
in second
in third
```

Answer (score 0):

super in Child tries to fetch information from Parent and the super in Parent tries to fetch information from GrandParent.

```
    public class Grandpapa {

    public void display() {
        System.out.println(" Grandpapa");
    }

    static class Parent extends Grandpapa{
        public void display() {
            super.display();
            System.out.println("parent");
        }
    }

    static class Child extends Parent{
        public void display() {
        //  super.super.display();// this will create error in Java
            super.display();
            System.out.println("child");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            Child cc = new Child();
            cc.display();
 /*
            * the output :
                 Grandpapa
                 parent
                 child
            */
    }
}
```